# Microsoft Entra Verifiable ID can not verify domain's ownership

Tags: verification, verify

When I upload the 'did-configuration.json' file in Azure web app, I can access the json file in edge url like:

```
'https://www.mydomainname.com/.well-known/did-configuration.json'
```

but Microsoft Entra Verifiable ID can not verify it.

I get this message:

> Your domain could not be validated. Please make sure you follow all of the provided steps.

How can I solve this?

I try to upload several 'did-configuration.json' to my web site, but no use.

And I buy a new domain from azure and upload a new generated 'did-configuration.json' from Microsoft Entra Verifiable ID and upload it in my Azure web app, but no use too.